# Google drive api max-age (cache)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

I have an application of google drive api (javascript)

The problem that I found is that the users can't see some folders
The solution is at max-age or using no-store.

I am suprised that I can't find any documentation about it.

Does someone know how I can implement the max-age in my full javascript app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also didn't find any documentation regarding `max-age` or `no-store`. If users cannot see some of your folders, you may want to check the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing) that determine whether or not users can perform actions on a file such as read or write.

> Use [`permissions.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) to grant additional permissions to a user, group, or domain. To change the assigned role, [`permissions.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/update).

You may also check on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/n1Bco4fbPqM) the possible workarounds which might help:

- Clear your [cookies and cache](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/32050?hl=en)
- Try [Incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)/[private window](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fprivate-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH5YTK-xMxBa1T3e2zbtbk-KMA4Ew)
- Disable [extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en)/[add-ons](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fdisable-or-remove-add-ons&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGd7cm5vfVHX9C4-Ur9LViGVCN_jw)/[plug-ins](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en)
- Try a different browser to see if it is a browser related issue